# Web request opening another website page but interaction with that page giving error

Tags: asp.net

I am opening a google page in my asp.net website,page is opening successfully but whenever i tried to interact with that page i am getting 404 error,if i try to search something 404 error is coming my code is below.

```
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com.pk/");
    myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
    myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    string tempProviderString = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        tempProviderString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Response.Write(tempProviderString);
```

Comment: are you getting httpwebresponse ?
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest .Create("https://www.google.com.pk/");

Comment: Yes google page is displaying but when i click on page search button for search something i am getting error.

Comment: [httpwebrequest-virtual-button-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583794/httpwebrequest-virtual-button-click)

Comment: I checked solution but it giving error remote server returned an error(405)on  line response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Answer (score 0):

First handle your 404 error.

```
try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com.pk/");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();          
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;          
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
               404 error....
            }
        }
```